# May i open a port on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: udp, port, cloud-foundry

I want to establish a UDP Connection from a terminal device to My App On Cloud Foundry.

Answer (score 2):

all output from applications on Cloud Foundry is delivered by proxy via a web server (nginx) and as far as I know only http and https are open.

Perhaps you should look at alternative ways of communicating with your console application, what kind of communication are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Using the CF_HOST:UDP_PORT from your terminal device should be OK. I suppose that an application (Java, Perl, etc) is deployed on your terminal device and on the CF server an application with a UDP channel is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but i've had a similar problem when porting my app to pivotal's cloud foundry platform.

Turns out you can continue to use tcp or udp for any outgoing traffic without doing any special configuration (e.g. service binding, etc) but only http or https for incoming traffic. However, there is an interesting workaround proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17878010/2215986)