# ApacheDS webapp and Cloudfoundry

Tags: ldap, cloud-foundry

I deployed an embedded apacheds application to public cloudfoundry! but i can't access it from ldap client in my machine!!
my server properties: 
host: http://kenzdz.cloudfoundry.com/
port: 10389
root dn: ou=system

when i use a class in the same project to acces the server,it success like the link show it:
 http://kenzdz.cloudfoundry.com/ldaptest : it is a servlet that acces the ldap server
but when i use a ldap client like jexplorer to acess remotely to the server it doesn't success.
is it because an embedded ldap server i cant do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudfoundry.com only allows inbound http(s) traffic on ports 80 and 443, respectively (see [May i open a port on Cloud Foundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756517/may-i-open-a-port-on-cloud-foundry)). So you won't be able to interact using the LDAP protocol with the app you deployed.